# Sinon js call for PUT or POST methods

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, mocking, sinon

I am using sinon js in my project for fake server call. Its working fine for GET calls but I have a scenario in which I want to mock a server with PUT or POST call.
I am doing it in this way:

```
server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); 
server.respondWith('PUT', /\/administration\/email/,
[204, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, JSON.stringify(EmailModelFixture)]);
```

---

```
emailView.save("abc@gmail.com");
server.respond();// Responding that save call.
```

But this is not working. Any one know how to fix it?

Comment: I am having the same issue no luck, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780530/sinons-fake-server-is-not-responding

Answer (score 3):

I've checked this scenario and it looks ok to me, so it works well.

Here is an example for Backbone

```
test("should submit PUT request", function() {
    var server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); 

    server.respondWith('PUT', /\/administration\/email/,
        [204, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, JSON.stringify({a:"1"})]);

    var spy_done = sinon.spy();
    var spy_fail = sinon.spy();

    var model = new (Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: "/administration/email/"
    }));

    // Save new model to generate PUT request
    model.save({ id: "test" }, {
        success: spy_done,
        error: spy_fail
    });

    server.respond();

    expect(spy_done.called).to.be.true;
    expect(spy_fail.called).to.be.false;
});
```

I'd recommend you to debug your ajax requests by dumping `server.requests` and check for url and method there to understand what's wrong.

Comment: I have have to registered GET response and also PUT response like this:
`server.respondWith('GET', /\/administration\/email/,
        [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, JSON.stringify({a:"1"})]);`
`server.respondWith('PUT', /\/administration\/email/,
        [204, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, JSON.stringify({a:"1"})]);`

if I comment out the GET registration then it works fine. So how can we register two methods calls?

Comment: I've checked with both at a time, and still works, even if I add new model which produce get request and server respond twice. Could you please update your question to include your test ?